# Are constants supported in ColdFusion?

Tags: coldfusion, constants, coldfusion-9

I am using ColdFusion 9 and have checked the documentation but it is ambiguous.

https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/developing-applications/the-cfml-programming-language/elements-of-cfml/constants.html

(I have PHP background and looking for something similar to PHP constants)

Thanks

Comment: The bit that says _"ColdFusion does not allow you to give names to constants."_ means that you cannot create your own constants (as you can with PHP's define function). You can of course just use variables and suitable coding guidelines, as [Miguel describes below](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16220215/are-constants-supported-in-coldfusion#16220446).

Answer (score 21, accepted):

No, ColdFusion does not have constants.  I think in most cases developers just set a variable, using some naming convention such as the variable name in ALL_CAPITALS, and then never change it's value.  This is not really a constant as in other languages and you really have to be careful that the value is not changed (because it is not a true constant).  I have done this before and typically set these "constants" in the application scope so they are readily available.

There was an [enhancement request](https://bugbase.adobe.com/index.cfm?event=bug&id=3197154) opened a while back. However, it looks like it has been closed and deferred.

Adam Cameron [blogged about this very thing last year](http://adamcameroncoldfusion.blogspot.com/2012/12/constants-for-cfml.html) and references the same enhancement request.

Answer (score 11):

No, not as a native language feature. the key bit in the page you linked to is "ColdFusion does not allow you to give names to constants"

I think the page is really talking about literals, rather than constants.

If you want to support unmodifiable constants, I think you'd need to use an object to encapsulate the values:

```
component displayname="constant values for my app" {
  property name="mailServer" default="127.0.0.1" getter=true setter=false
  property name="password" default="supersecret" getter=true setter=false
}
```

You could then set this in whichever scope you need it (e.g. application or request) then call application.constants.getMailServer()

It's not as concise as the @Miguel-F solution, which is the one I'd use most of the time, but it's here as another option.

Answer (score 2):

ColdFusion 2018 and above supports the key word `final`. Final is a lot like a constant, except that it does not have to be set when declared. Once it is set it cannot be changed.

```
// This is good
function myExample(){
    final max=50;
    writeoutput("final variable is: " & max);
}


// This is bad
function myExample(){
    final max=50;
    max = 100
    writeoutput("final variable is: " & max);
}
```

For more info see: https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/developing-applications/building-blocks-of-coldfusion-applications/object-oriented-programming-coldfusion.html#final

Comment: Ah, didn't know about `final`.  Though style-wise, my preference placing `final` variable declarations  *outside* functions. Otherwise, it's easy to mistake them for local variables.